# Flutter ReorderableListView example

Tags: dart, flutter

Can anyone show how to make this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> _list = List.generate(5, (i) => "${i}");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ReorderableListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        children: _list.map((String string) => ListTile(key: Key(_list[_list.indexOf(string)]), title: Text(string))).toList(),
        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
          String old = _list[oldIndex];
          if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
            for (int i = oldIndex; i > newIndex; i--) {
              _list[i] = _list[i - 1];
            }
            _list[newIndex] = old;
          } else {
            for (int i = oldIndex; i < newIndex - 1; i++) {
              _list[i] = _list[i + 1];
            }
            _list[newIndex - 1] = old;
          }
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option, instead of directly adjusting index values:

```
 if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
   newIndex -= 1;
 }
 final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
 _items.insert(newIndex, item);
```

As can be seen in an example on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html.

Comment: I upvoted this because it seemed elegant, then realised it will throw a `RangeError` if you move an item to the end of the list - because you remove an item first (reducing the list size by 1), then attempt to insert an item at the last index, but that index is no longer valid. SO wont let me take back my upvote.

Comment: Certainly fair. I've minused it to remove it.
This is a commonly noted thing in flutter ReorderableList. I think (without checking), it's common to add this line of code ahead of this to address this issue:
if (_newIndex > _oldIndex) { _newIndex -= 1;}
If I circle back to confirm I will edit
EDIT: oops, i can't downvote my own post either I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to do this myself today. Was not satisfied with either answer. Here is what I came up with.

```
 ReorderableListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
    buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
    onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
       test.insert(newIndex, test[oldIndex]);
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
             test.removeAt(oldIndex);
          } else {
             test.removeAt(oldIndex + 1);
          }
             setState(() {});
    },
    children: test.asMap().entries.map((e) {
       return ReorderableDragStartListener(
       index: e.key,
       key: Key(e.key.toString() + e.value),
       child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          child: Card(
           child: Center(child: Text(e.value)),
            elevation: 4,
            ),
          ),
         );
       }).toList(),
    ),
```

It this avoids the unneeded loops in user6274128's answer, and doesn't have the bug in Scott's answer. It also avoids bugs with index being based on the List.indexof as that will return the first instance of the String instead of the correct one.